# Can I install and run Ubuntu on Celeron j3455 processor?

Tags: system-installation, system-requirements

I'm getting a budget laptop, and I want to make sure it would run ubuntu 20.4 fine. I know the minimum requirement is 2gh dual-core, but I never had experience with this processor before. here are more specs of the laptop:

256 SSD
1080p
CPU: Intel celeron_j3455 quad-core
CPU frequency: 1.5GHz up to 2.3Ghz
Memory: LPDDR3 6GB

Thank you!

Edit: Usage purpose mainly browser, Spotify, videos, "heaviest" thing would be nodejs for school.

Comment: Please refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll note "*Shopping or Hardware Recommendations*" are off-topic.  Ubuntu Forums allows those sort of *opinion* based questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is "the Celeron J3455 *will work* with Ubuntu", but the qualifier of "fine" will be very difficult to judge ahead of time. [Looking at the benchmarks for that processor](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Celeron+J3455+%40+1.50GHz&id=2875), you're going to find it rather sluggish with just about everything. As a result, you may want to look at one of the lighter-weight flavours, such as [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org) or [Ubuntu MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org).

Comment: Thank you for your response! That's good to know, yeah I was planning to use it lightly browser, music, videos, the "heaviest" thing would be a nodejs server for school. But that's good to know, it would be sluggish and there is a lighter version.